# Character variable not getting printed correctly while using cin and cout

Tags: c++, input, output, long-integer

I have to write a program which takes an input which consists of the following space-separated values: int, long, char, float, and double, respectively and then print each of these values in a new line in the output.

When I'm writing the program using printf and scanf, it works perfectly fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    scanf("%d %ld %c %f %lf", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    printf("%d\n%ld\n%c\n%f\n%lf", a, b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I'm using cin and cout, there's some problem happening. It happens when the number being entered for long is greater than LONG_MAX.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int intNumber;
    long longNumber;
    char character;
    float floatNumber;
    double doubleNumber;
    cin>>intNumber>>longNumber>>character>>floatNumber>>doubleNumber;                
    cout<<intNumber<<"\n"<<longNumber<<"\n"<<character<<"\n"<<floatNumber<<"\n"<<doubleNumber;
   return 0;
}
```

For example, if the input is 211916801 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465, the first program's output is

```
211916801
97592151379235457
p
19856.992
-5279235.721231465
```

But, the second program's out is

```
211916801
2147483647
╠
-1.07374e+08
-9.25596e+61
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: The `long` looks like it's being treated as an `int`.  The `char` looks like an encoding issue.  You're not having these problems with `printf` because the format specifiers in `printf` know what to do.

Comment: I think the `cin>>` gave up after the out-of-range input for `longNumber` (assuming `long` is 32-bits for this compiler). Try initializing the variables to see which variables still have their initial values (and haven't been updated by `cin>>`) at the time of the `cout<<`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`istream::operator>>` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) calls the [`std::num_get::get` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) which calls the `std::num_get::do_get` function.

The `do_get` function does parsing in three stages, and for [stage 3 (conversion and storage)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get#Stage_3:_conversion_and_storage) there is this note:

> If the conversion function results in a positive value too large to fit in the type of `v`, the most positive representable value is stored in `v`

[Note: `v` is the destination variable]

This explains what happens in with the value, and why you get `2147483647` for the `long` value. We can also from this say that you're on a system where the size of `long` is still 32 bits.

The list of notes for stage 3 then continues:

> In any case, if the conversion function fails [`std::ios_base::failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is assigned to `err`

And that explains what happens with the rest of the values. Once `failbit` is set you can't read more from the input stream until you clear the state.

---

Furthermore, if we go back to the [`operator>>` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) we see that for C++98 and C++03

> If extraction fails ... value is left unmodified and `failbit` is set.

And for C++11 and later

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value

Since your variables after the `failbit` is set are not zero then we can deduce that you're building this with a pre-C++11 compiler. The values you print are the uninitialized contents which is *indeterminate*. And even reading indeterminate contents leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: In that case, how does scanf() works perfectly fine?

Comment: @SaurabhPrakash Because the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function doesn't work like the C++ "input" operators.

Answer (score 0):

You inputed a long number is out of MAX_LONG = 2147483647. So that in this case it is overflow issue.